# EF: An error occurred while updating the entries

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I ask for a help. This code doesn`t work

```
switch (productid)
            {
                case ("Forester"):
                    prdct = db.Products.Find(2);
                    break;
                case ("Impreza"):
                    prdct = db.Products.Find(3);
                    break;
                case ("Legacy"):
                    prdct = db.Products.Find(4);
                    break;
                case ("Tribeca"):
                    prdct = db.Products.Find(5);
                    break;
                case ("XV"):
                    prdct = db.Products.Find(6);
                    break;
                case ("OutBack"):
                    prdct = db.Products.Find(7);
                    break;
            }

cstmr = db.Customers.Find(id);
pchase.CustomerID = cstmr.Id;
pchase.ProductID = prdct.Id;
pchase.PurchaseDate = DateTime.Now;
pchase.PurchaseDate = DateTime.Now;
pchase.ProductsQuantity = 2;
db.Purchases.Add(pchase);
db.SaveChanges();
```

BUT, almost the same method works

```
cstmr = db.Customers.Find(Convert.ToInt32(pw.customerid.Text));
prdct = db.Products.Find(Convert.ToInt32(pw.productid.Text));
pchase.CustomerID = cstmr.Id;
pchase.ProductID = prdct.Id;
pchase.PurchaseDate = (DateTime)pw.purchasedate.SelectedDate;
pchase.DeliveryDate = (DateTime)pw.deliverydate.SelectedDate;
pchase.ProductsQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(pw.quantity.SelectedItem);
```

'id' is customer's Id and passed to method correctly
My attempts to fix this were in vain, I have no idea what to do.

[image]

Comment: can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: which part doesn't work?

Comment: Let me guess... try to set `DeliveryDate` property =)

Comment: Omg, probably I pasted two the same properties instead of two different ones. that.s my the most stupid mistake :D Thank you!

Comment: Next time post the actual error message too please, it's much easier to diagnose.

Comment: The exception message will say _"See the InnerException for details"_. Then see the `InnerException` property of the exception for details.